# Execute PHP without leaving page

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I have a form - textarea (named `su`) and submit button.

When the form is submitted, I need to

1. run a PHP script without refreshing/leaving page
2. "echo" or somehow print a return on the screen

I'm pretty sure this works via some kind of ajax request thing. but I have no idea how.

Like I said I'm uneducated with ajax or java. A quick example would be wonderful.

Comment: Quick example neither educate you. Why not to find yourself an online tutorial?

Answer (score 8):

Simple , that is what is called AJAX. The solution is more of Javascript, than PHP.

Using Jquery, you can do it with a simple function call:

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#ID_Of_Your_Button').change(function(){
             $.ajax({
                   type: "GET",
                   url: "send.php",
                   data: "query="+document.form.textarea.value,
                   success: function(msg){
                    document.getElementById("Div_Where_you_want_the_response").innerHTML = msg                         }
                 })
        });
    });

</script>
```

Does the trick.

Comment: Alright dude just what i was looking for. I filled in all the placeholders you gave me and my jquery file is the latest and available, but for some reason this isn't working. I've also change the "query" in data to just "su", changed TYPE to POST (in your script) and adjusted my PHP page to grab the "su" data via POST.
<br><br>It's still not working. I have no clue what the problem is - everything corresponds and matches up perfectoly between the form, script and PHP page..

Comment: I have had similar PHP problems with the script running locally from a hard drive. It will probably work properly if you upload and run it from the internet.

Answer (score 1):

If your just now getting into ajax, PHP, and JQuery I would highly suggest using firefox and installing [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/). Learn to use it and it will tell you all sorts of great things. There is not enough space to tell you everything it does, but it is ,at this point, one of my best debugging tools. Learn it, Love it and good luck.

Answer (score 0):

It is usually best to use a Javascript library for doing AJAX.

See [jQuery.get()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) for one way to send a request to a PHP web page using the jQuery library. You can have your PHP page output Javascript to be executed, or output plain text or data.

Comment: OKaay thanks. I'm working on my own here trying to piece things together. Implemented one of the examples on the linked page you gave me, but i have one q. How do I tie my form action to the function i just created?

function:

  $.get("back/update.php", { name: "John", time: "2pm" },
   function(data){
     alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
   });

Comment: There's a jQuery plugin called jQuery forms for that:
http://plugins.jquery.com/project/form

The syntax is fairly similar and the examples explain most of it, I think.