# HTML form submit: open PHP in invisible browser tab

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am writing an HTML application that passes a bunch of form elements along to a PHP script, that will run a Python script using those values.

The form element in my page looks like:

```
<form id="main-input" action="shell.php" method="post" target="_blank">
```

This opens a new tab, with the PHP script inside. It is an otherwise blank page, with no text on it (since there is asynchronous data display).

Since I do not want the user to mistakenly close this tab (since it would stop script execution) and also since it could cause other confusion, **is there a way to make the new browser tab invisible, but still active, using HTML?**

More to the point, **is there a way to have an invisible broswer tab?**

Comment: You should look into AJAX

Comment: Google ajax and read read read. Ajax is your best friend.

Comment: I saw this: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2954961/execute-php-without-leaving-page] about Ajax, and this is what I plan on using. Yes, Ajax would solve the problem I have, but I asked this question simply out of curiosity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question, No you cannot have an invisible browser tag.

Comment: Although true to the fact that you can't have an "invisible browser tab", the OP can complete this via doing an AJAX request.

Comment: Yes, and I commented that, but that is not the answer to the question.

Comment: This is what I suspected, but I just wanted to make sure.

Comment: @bcdan Yeah, for security mainly. Please check the checkmark next to my answer if I answered your question.

Comment: I am going to wait to see if there are any better answers. If not, I will do so in a couple days.

Comment: Better answer? There is no other answer...Browser will never allow you to open an invisible browser tab, advertisers and hackers would love it. You will need to ask another question to get info about ajax. The question you asked is answered.

Comment: Just stop pestering. You'll probably get it anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Ehm, just have an invisible iframe and post to it with form target.
It is not really an invisible browser tab, yet the most close you get to it - maybe an inline browser tab :)

```
<form id="main-input" action="shell.php" method="post" target="anyname"></form>
<iframe name = 'anyname' src = 'blubb.php' style = 'display: none'></iframe>
```

No need for AJAX so far and the nearest to your idea as possible.

Answer (score -1):

Answer: No, there's no way that I know of to make an invisible browser tab (for security and annoyance reasons).

Suggestion: Instead of posting to another tab, you should submit a Post using ajax instead. Override the normal submit action of the form...

https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8#q=override%20submit%20form&es_th=1

... and then proceed to gather the form values and compile a Post request. Here's a jQuery reference to using Ajax... 
http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_get_post.asp

Here's a more general JavaScript reference from W3 Schools:
http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp

Comment: The question is answered. Links are for comments.