# Clicking URL to php page (to load cookies only) that does not load and stay in current page

Tags: javascript, php, html, cookies, hyperlink

I want to create an hyperlink() to a PHP file in server that runs the PHP without open a new page, staying in the page where I click the hyperlink.

Consideration 1: Without JS or jQuery, etc in the page where the `<a>` is.
Consideration 2: PHP code has to run completely without open it in a new page. web user do not feel changes in the current page and stay in the same page.

HTML:

```
<a href="http://localhost/test_site/php/create_cookie.php?name=Alan&lastname=Harper">Save your name for future access.</a>
```

PHP:

```
<?php //create_cookie.php
`$cookie_name = "user_name";
$cookie_value = $_GET['name'] . " " . $_GET['lastname'];
setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, time() + 86400, "/");
$_COOKIE['$cookie_name'] = $cookie_value;`
```

?>

Comment: You cannot run php via a client without 1) reloading the page/navigating away or 2) using js/jquery ajax call. This is because PHP is a server side language and a request must make it to the server to execute a script.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Execute PHP without leaving page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2954961/execute-php-without-leaving-page)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just redirect back in the PHP-file to the file with the link, and set the redirect-time to 0.

Something like `header('location: <originalfile>');` at the bottom of the php-file.

Comment: Thanks... i did it using $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], instead of <originalfile>.